# Does iText7 support the PdfTemplate for creating Header and Footer like it does in iTextSharp?

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm new to iText7. The question might be very trivial. When using iTextSharp, I was able to create PdfTemplate first and then use PdfContentByte.AddTemplate to add additional contents to the template for header and footer. The Footer template was very useful in getting the Page # of total# when closing the document. 
Does iText7 have similar feature? If not, what can be used for achieving this?

Thanks for your helps in advance!
Baolin

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38605857/1729265) to ["How to add a “Page X of Y” footer in iText 7"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38588704/1729265); it is for Java but should be trivial to port.

Comment: Yes, I've checked out that and it worked for me. Thanks.