# Total page number is displaying wrong in pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext

Total Page number is not dispplaying in generated pdf.

After reading the following post [PDF Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205777/pdf-page-numbering-in-java-itext)    I generated the following code, but it show the following output:

First Page:-

```
        Page 1 of 1
```

Second Page:-

### Page 2 of 1

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class LogoHeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

    String header;
    int totalNumber = 0;
    PdfTemplate total;

    public void setHeader(String header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public void onOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        total = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 12);
        System.out.println("No : "+writer.getPageNumber());
        System.out.println("PDF Template : "+total);
    }

    public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        //total = writer.getDirectContent().createTemplate(30, 12);
        writer.setPageCount(++totalNumber);
        System.out.println("Page No : "+writer.getPageNumber());
        System.out.println("Total No : "+totalNumber);
        //totalNumber++; 
    }
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.NORMAL);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        try {
            table.setWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2});
            table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(10);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setBorder (0);
            cell.setBorderWidthTop (1);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("", ffont));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.setBorder (0);
            cell.setBorderWidthTop (1);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            cell.setPhrase(new Phrase(String.format("Page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()), ffont));
            table.addCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(total));
            cell.setBorder (0);
            cell.setBorderWidthTop (1);
            table.addCell(cell);
            table.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth()
                    - document.leftMargin() - document.rightMargin());
            table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.leftMargin(),
                    document.bottomMargin() - 15, writer.getDirectContent());

        }
        catch(DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }

    public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {

        Font ffont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.UNDEFINED, 10, Font.NORMAL);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1), ffont),
                2, 1, 0);
    }

}
```

not able to find the bug in this code, Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me, there must be something wrong with the creation of the document.

In the small test below I create a PDF document with three pages using your helper class and each page has the correct footer set (*1/3*, *2/3* and *3/3*).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("dest.pdf"));
    LogoHeaderFooter logoHeaderFooter = new LogoHeaderFooter();
    writer.setPageEvent(logoHeaderFooter);

    document.open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ) {
        i++;
        document.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph " + i));
        document.newPage();
    }
    document.close();
}
```